# Lda2Vec on Python 2.7

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, lda, word2vec

Good afternoon.

I'm trying to run the lda2vec algorithm that i got from https://github.com/cemoody/lda2vec and i just can't make it work. At the moment i'm trying the twenty_newsgroups examples. One method from the code was deprecated and i changed the method.
After this change i the preprocess.py file works fine but when i try to run lda2vec_run.py the type of vectors doesn't match.
Do you have any idea of how to resolve this issues? Do i have to make anymore modifications on the code?

Greetings
João Silva

Comment: Hi JoaoSilva, Did this work for you??